# Не могу разобраться с ответом JSON

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Вкратце, в интерфейсе прописал метод, а в Application классе привязал retrofit

```
@GET("/v1/fixtures/{matchId}")
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> getEvents(@Path("matchId") int matchId);

static FootballApi sFootballApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://api.football-data.org")
                .build().create(FootballApi.class);
```

В активити:

```
observable = App.getAPIJson().getEvents(159316);
        observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.i(TAG, "JSON, onCompleted");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "SOMETHING WRONG WITH JSON: " + e.getMessage().toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

В логе (onNext) получаю: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://api.football-data.org/v1/fixtures/159316}

Я так понял код 200 означает успешное получение данных, но как их теперь достать?

Comment: перейти по присланному url, даже сейчас можете по нему нажать и увидеть свой ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ сервера в теле. Получить его можно так:

```
String answer = response.body().string();
```

Comment: Вопрос! Здесь происходит дессериализация response? Почему нужно брать эту конструкцию в try/catch?

Comment: @cosmic_M, в исходники я не смотрел но да, тут надо быть аккуратным. Например, помещать `response.body().string();` в отдельную переменную и с ней работать. Я лично встречал ситуации, когда повторный вызов этой конструкции возвращал `null`